# Convert "& aring;" "& ouml;" to its normal representation

Tags: c#, character-encoding, html-agility-pack, iso-8859-1

I'm loading a web page `System.Net.WebClient`. Page is in `ISO-8859-1` encoding. 
If I write it to file and then open, I can see all characters normally.

But if I put this content into HtmlAgilityPack and then extract innerText property,
I'm getting some special letter encoded as `&aring;` and `&ouml;` .

How to convert them to normal representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) method

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&aring;"); // å
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick help!!

Comment: As someone pointed out on another thread, this can be a problem because HttpUtility is located in System.Web.dll which can be a problem at least in the case of the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile which does not contains this assembly. The HtmlEntity.DeEntitize (see corvuscorax answer) method is included with the Html Agility Pack.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `HtmlEntity.DeEntitize` method with the text string as the parameter.